# Can I convert a parallels virtual machine (pvm file) to a windows virtual pc or other free virtualization software?

Tags: virtualization

I have a pvm file with an image of windows 7 in it. I want to be able to open this on a windows computer. I don't mind what virtualization to use so long as it's free, so probably either virtualbox or windows virtual pc.

Any idea how to convert it to either of these, or to another free virtual machine piece of software?

Comment: Thanks, I tried googling all kinds of combinations but it seems you've cracked it with that one.